# How can I duplicate Quicksight Dashboards programmatically for different groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

I have searched everywhere but I can't find a way to achieve this, maybe someone else has had the same issue.

I have a dashboard in Quicksight using a particular dataset which corresponds to one client's data. I would like to recreate the same dashboard multiple times using datasets which have the same structure but correspond to other clients each time. I want to do this programmatically because in reality there are many clients and many datasets involved in each dashboard so it will be difficult to do manually in Quicksight's UI without making mistakes.

I've been playing around with APIs and AWS CLI commands, so I've discovered using templates but to my dismay this seems to only be useful for versioning rather than creating different dashboards from a 'template' where you only need to specify a new dataset.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Please let me know if you have had any luck with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with templates and the AWS CLI, API, or SDK

1. Create a template from your analysis using [create-template](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/create-template.html)
2. Create a new dashboard from this template and a specific dataset using [create-dashboard](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/create-dashboard.html). The dataset placeholder specified in the source-entity parameter must match the name of the dataset referenced in your template, so that Quicksight can replace it with your new dataset.